# Pass GeoPackage layer attributes to marker popup in leaflet without click on the marker

Tags: leaflet, popup, leaflet-plugins

I am working on querying a GeoPackage layer based on leaflet and leaflet-geosearch.

Here is the plain js code.

```js
import './style.css'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css';


import L from 'leaflet'

import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

import '@ngageoint/leaflet-geopackage';

let provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
  provider: provider,
  autoComplete: true, // optional: true|false  - default true
  autoCompleteDelay: 250,
  style: 'bar'
});


const map = L.map('map', {
  center: [15.50, 75],
  zoom: 5
});
map.addControl(searchControl);


L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(map);

  L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
    geoPackageUrl: 'mycustomgeopackage.gpkg',
    layerName: 'temm',
    style: function(feature) {
      return {
        color: '#F00',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 0.5,
      };
    },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer){
          var name = feature.properties.city_served;
          layer.bindPopup('Name: ' + name ).openPopup();
      }
  }).addTo(map);
```

I was able to load the geopackage as well as perform the geosearch using the above code. I have added so that I can display the properties of cities served.

```
onEachFeature: function( feature, layer){
          var name = feature.properties.city_served;
          layer.bindPopup('Name: ' + name ).openPopup();
      }
```

But, I see the city information only 'click' event on the feature class. How can I pass this information to marker popup and display the popup without the click event?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to have permanently opened/shown label on feature?

Comment: leaflet geosearch plugin generates only 1 marker. For each new search the old marker is replaced by a new one.

Comment: And you want info about Geopackage layer feature under search marker to be displayed in search marker popup?

Comment: Yes. that is what i am aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no other solution than to search in GeoPackage layer for feature that contains search result coordinate (using [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library) and use GeoSearchControl `popupFormat` option to add that info to search result popup.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var geoPackageLayer = L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
  geoPackageUrl: 'mycustomgeopackage.gpkg',
  layerName: 'temm',
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      color: '#F00',
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 0.5,
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: function( feature, layer){
    var name = feature.properties.city_served;
    layer.bindPopup('Name: ' + name ).openPopup();
  }
}).addTo(map);
  
function popupFormat(search) {
  var point = turf.point([search.result.x, search.result.y]);
  var layers = geoPackageLayer.getLayers();
  var featureInfo = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point, layers[i].feature)) {
      featureInfo = '<br>Name: ' + layers[i].feature.properties.city_served;
      break;
    }
  };
  return(search.result.label + featureInfo);
}

const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
  provider: provider,
  autoComplete: true
  autoCompleteDelay: 250,
  style: 'bar',
  popupFormat: popupFormat
});
```

Below is an example of search result popup, where info second line comes from GeoPackage feature under result marker:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was avoiding to use turf so that I can save some computing time, but it looks like there is no avoiding this. this solution works perfectly.